# Flask Admin Ckeditor Image Upload is not working

Tags: image, upload, ckeditor, flask-admin

I am trying to integrate flask-ckeditor to work with flask-admin. I have followed all the guidance in the documentation and I was able to make ckeitor work within flask admin view. The issue is image upload not appearing and not working even though I have followed the example provided in flask-admin-upload. I also tried to search in stackoverflow and other search platform for similar issues, but sadly I couldn't find any solution.

here is my config file

```
class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'alskjdfoisflkjsmkdjfoijsdfksjflksdif'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/blogdb"
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','PNG','JPG','JPEG'])
    CKEDITOR_SERVE_LOCAL = False
    CKEDITOR_HEIGHT = 1000
    CKEDITOR_FILE_BROWSER = 'main.upload'
    CKEDITOR_FILE_UPLOADER = 'main.upload'
    UPLOADED_PATH = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/img')
    FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT = True
```

and here is my admin.py file

```
class PostView(CustomModelView):
    can_view_details = True
    column_list = ['title','image','tags', 'category']
    form_columns = ('title', 
                    'image',
                    'tags',
                    'lede',
                    'content',
                    'author',
                    'category_id'
                    )

    form_extra_fields = {
        'image': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
                                      base_path=file_path,
                                               )
    }

    form_overrides  = {
        'content': CKEditorField
    }

    create_template = 'admin/create.html'
    edit_template = 'admin/edit.html'
```

and here is my admin/create.html template

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% import 'admin/lib.html' as lib with context %}
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import extra with context %} {# backward compatible #}

{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
  {{ lib.form_css() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {% block navlinks %}
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ return_url }}" class="nav-link">{{ _gettext('List') }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link active">{{ _gettext('Create') }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  {% endblock %}

  {% block create_form %}
    {{ lib.render_form(form, return_url, extra(), form_opts) }}
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block tail %}
  {{ super() }}
  {{ lib.form_js() }}
  {{ ckeditor.load() }}
  {{ ckeditor.config(name='text') }}
{% endblock %}
```

any guidance, would be appreciated?

Thanks in advance

I have tried to follow flask documentations and examples, searching for similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the issue.
The problem lies within the ckeditor configuration in the html template which is supposed to be passed with "text" name as per the flask documentation suggestion `{{ ckeditor.config(name='text') }}`.

However, neither "text" nor "content" (which is the variable name in my model) is working, and they seem to be overlapping with other functions within flask-admin.

By changing that to a different name, and passing it to html ckeditor.config, the problem is solved, and uploading is working.